# Faster way to count number of elements in a list in ranges specified by elements of another list

Tags: python, numpy

I wonder whether there exists a faster way to count the number of values in a list in ranges specified by values of another list. Currently, I used `bisect_left`, but this requires `sorted` priori, which have been shown to reduce the efficiency of the codes. Any faster solution?
The codes are:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from _bisect import bisect_left
>>> import time
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> list1 = [np.random.randn(200) for i in xrange(3)]
>>> list2 = [np.random.randn(80) for i in xrange(1000)]
>>> def test():
    tt = time.time()
    list2x = [sorted(x) for x in list2]
    for x in list1:
        nr = []
        nrapp = nr.append
        for y in list2x:
            lj = len(y)
            bx = [bisect_left(y, xk) for xk in x]
            nk = sum(1 for k,xk in izip(bx, x) if (k>0 and xk-y[k-1]<=0.2) or (k<lj and y[k]-xk<=0.2))
            nrapp(nk)
    print time.time()-tt


>>> for i in xrange(10): test()

0.786000013351
0.608999967575
0.546999931335
0.575000047684
0.629999876022
0.59299993515
0.546999931335
0.536000013351
0.575000047684
0.625
```

A single example for this aim can be:

```
>>> x1 = np.random.randn(10)
>>> x1
array([ 0.43165934, -0.11926191,  1.7257972 , -0.92569184,  1.37651344,
    1.26895329,  0.89498147,  0.32699621,  0.11069324, -0.00309866])
>>> x2 = np.random.randn(20)
>>> x2
array([-0.65556355, -1.680542  ,  1.07821383, -1.14390854, -1.13806358,
    0.01698883, -1.44074658,  1.41329607, -0.92578986, -1.87628167,
   -0.50014942, -0.02853544,  2.16239462,  0.50030708,  1.11585082,
   -0.55437825,  0.47246503,  0.59957544, -1.59937406, -1.8100736 ])
>>> sum(any(abs(xk-xj)<=0.2 for xk in x2) for xj in x1)
9
```

Which wants to count the number of values in `x1` locates in the `[-0.2, 0.2]` tolerance of any values in `list x2`

Comment: Something wrong with the posted answer that made you unaccept it?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get final result for comparing your `broadcasting` to bisect search. For my preliminary results, it doesn't show significant improvement in large iterations. So before the really fair comparison comes out, I would not accept it. I think if every list has been sorted, bisect search can be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach #1 : Using [`searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)** -

```
x2s = np.sort(x2) # or x2.sort() and use x2 instead of x2s
idx0 = np.searchsorted(x2s,x1).clip(max=len(x2s)-1)
idx1 = (idx0-1).clip(min=0)
out = ((np.abs(x2s[idx0]-x1) <= 0.2) | (np.abs(x1-x2s[idx1]) <= 0.2)).sum()
```

**Approach #2 : Using [`broadcasting`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/ufuncs.html#broadcasting)** -

```
(np.abs(x1[:,None] - x2)<=0.2).any(1).sum()
```

To leverage [`multi-core` with `numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/blob/master/doc/user_guide.rst#enabling-intel-vml-support) for large data -

```
import numexpr as ne

ne.evaluate('abs(x1e-x2)<=0.2',{'x1e':x1[:,None]}).any(1).sum()
```